# Why can't I stabilize a critically wounded solider in XCOM: Enemy Unknown when standing right on top of him?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In XCOM: Enemy Unknown, I have a critically wounded solider that is bleeding out, with the red cross and turns-until-death counter showing 1 turn left, and the message saying the solider can be revived or stabilized.

Another solider, a high-ranking support unit, has used his first action to move right on top of the wounded soldier. However, the stabilize action is faded out and not available. When I choose it, it says there is no soldier in Medikit range.

It looks like the support unit is standing right over the wounded soldier. The purple Medikit range circle is showing, and the support unit is right at the center of it. The support unit has the x3 Medikit ability; two have been used, with 1x available.

This is on the iPad version.

From what I can tell, this is a bug -- a very sad one, as I'm going to lose one of my favorite soldiers, with no saved game to go back to. If so, I'll have to chalk it up to Medikit malfunction.

Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: It might be a design choice, because it might clash with the revive-ability which brings the critically injured soldier back to action where he lies. When the support would stand right on top of him, you would have two units in one space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the PC version, I'm pretty sure you can't stand on top of another character, you have to stand next to him in order to stabilize, heal or revive. If you're standing on top of the character, as in, occupying same block, that sounds like a glitch.

Comment: Yeah that's what I think. Hard to tell for sure, as the wounded soldier is lying down but it does look like the two soldiers are occupying the same block. Sigh. There goes my beloved trooper :-)

Answer (score -1):

Just move over a square.  Works for me.

Comment: If I move over a square, turn is over and the poor guy dies.

Answer (score -2):

The game is bugged, same issue also on the PC, it shouldn't but it does let you place a unit right on top of the wounded. But that's a small issue you can just avoid yourself. The bigger bug is that even after stabilizing units correctly they still end up KIA. So entirely pointless to even try. Just reload to an earlier save-point and try to avoid the same situation all over again.

Personally I feel the studio behind the game isn't capable of handling the responsibility of having to fix bugs in their games post-release and will not buy anything developed by them again.

Comment: Do you feel your answer adds valuable info to Chippies' answer given over three years ago?